# Gnome-calendar crash

Tags: 17.04, crash, calendar

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 (quite new to Linux I must say) and since then, I've been getting a lot of errors which did not seem to impact my experience (nor do I actually know how to trace them back or fix them...)

However, I am now trying to synchronize the Ubuntu Calendar with my Google Calendar, but I keep getting errors from Ubuntu Calendar. Since my calendar is an important part of my daily life, this is something which is actually important to me.

I am not sure how to export the information about the error, so here are screenshots of the error:

--Top of message--
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FozZ3.jpg

--Bottom of message--
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEEPY.jpg

If someone could help me out to fix this, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't know that it will help, but I sync my Google calendars with Thunderbird, and find that this works quite well.

Comment: @CharlesGreen With Lthe Lightning addon? Also, do you know if it is possible with Thunderbird to connect my Google calendar to a my business email address instead of my google address? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the lightning add-on.  I believe that you can share your Google calendar with other non-google addresses - I started using it because it makes a common source for my computer, my android phone, and my (no longer present) iphone.  I am also able to add other peoples calendars, such as the calendar for my son's school.